# How to pass the value from content to sidebar in angular4?

Tags: angular4-forms

```js
export class CreateOrderComponent implements OnInit 
{
    myorder = new Order(0,0,0);
    onSubmit(value){  
        console.log('you submitted value:',value); 
        this.pickup(); 
    }
    constructor(private router: Router) { }
    pickup() {
        this.router.navigate(['/pickupLocation']); 
    }
    shipper() {
        this.router.navigate(['/shipper']); 
    }
    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

I am trying to pass the object from my form to sidebar in the similar page. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Input to share data to another child component.
Take a look to following links.

https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/building-nested-components-in-angular-2/

https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2016/12/13/communication-between-components-using-input-in-angular-2.aspx